# Is there a way to check if a JavaScript function accepts a callback?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, web-component, localforage

I am trying to add [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) support to the [pure-form](https://github.com/john-doherty/pure-form) Web Component by creating a global instance of localForage:

```
// create a global appStorage object that mimics localStorage API (greater storage)
window.appStorage = localforage.createInstance({
    driver: [
        localforage.INDEXEDDB,
        localforage.WEBSQL,
        localforage.LOCALSTORAGE
    ],
    name: 'product-name',
    version: 1.0,
    storeName: 'app'
});
```

And assigning it to an instance of pure-form via the `storage` attribute:

```
<pure-form src="path-to-schema.json" storage="appStorage"></pure-form>
```

Internally, pure-form executes `window[self.storage]` to get a handle to the storage object and uses `.getItem`, `.setItem` to set and retrieve values synchronously.

Trouble is localForage is asynchronous, meaning `.getItem`, `.setItem` expect to return values via a callback. Therefore my current logic won't work:

```
// get value from web storage
var storedContent = window[self.storage].getItem('item-key');
```

I realise I could wrap the call in a Promise, but as it stands pure-form does not require promises and I'd hate to add that dependency just for this.

What I would like to do is check if `.getItem` or `.setItem` require a callback, and if so, modify the code accordingly...

Comment: You check the docs-there's no way to tell without looking at the source or docs. That said, almost any async call either takes a callback or uses promises.

Comment: So then I guess the alternative would be to attempt to determine if the storage is an instance of localForage? Trouble is, that becomes a hard coded edge case

Comment: You could test `.getItem.length` is more than 1. There is no guarantee the extra parameter appears in the function declaration, but if it does, it will be at least 2.

Comment: If you were going to modify the pureform code anyway, why not just rewrite it directly to work with localforage? Btw, adding asynchrony to a codebase is no simple feat, you might have to start from the ground up.

Comment: @Bergi Because I don't want to force others to use localforage

Comment: @trincot I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Functions have a [length property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) which specifies the number of arguments expected by the function. If it expects a callback, it would expect one more argument than if it didn't. However, you must be cautious, as a function declaration does not need to specify any parameters, as it can deal with the `arguments` variable instead. And in that case the `length` is zero. Or it could be hybrid...

Comment: @JohnDoherty Wouldn't you modify the code for yourself only?

Comment: @Bergi I could but I'd then loose the ability to inherit any community updates... without significant effort to merge changes.

Comment: @JohnDoherty So you were thinking about merging your changes upstream, and getting the library to support asynchrony by default? Good luck with that, but you will definitely need to discuss such a thing with the maintainers, not here on SO. In any case, if that is the route you want to go, use promises. Assume that every function possibly returns a promise (and cast other values to one using `Promise.resolve`), so it will work with both synchronous and asynchronous implementations.

Comment: @Bergi I am one of the maintainers, so applied the changes directly to the repo... pure-form is used in a number of commercial hybrid mobile apps that do not support promises. Which would mean any updates to them apps would force them to pull in the Promise polyfill. It's also worth noting pure-form is an encapsulated web component, so you interact with it like a regular HTML tag, by settings properties and listening for events. It does not expose any callbacks/promises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Dave-Newton pointed out in the comments:

> there's no way to tell without looking at the source or docs. That said, almost any async call either takes a callback or uses promises.

Based on that, I created two functions that wrap calls to `.getItem` and `.setItem` and inspects their responses. If they return an instance of **Promise**, it resolves using `.then` - otherwise executes the callback as normal:

```
/**
 * Get a value from web storage regardless of whether it's sync or async
 */
function getStorageItem(storage, key, callback) {

    if (typeof callback !== 'function') throw new Error('Invalid callback handler');

    var result = storage.getItem(key);

    if (result instanceof window.Promise) {
        result.then(callback);
    }
    else {
        callback(result);
    }
}

/**
 * Set a value in web storage regardless of whether it's sync or async
 */
function setStorageItem(storage, key, value, callback) {

    var result = storage.setItem(key, value);

    if (result instanceof window.Promise && callback) {
        result.then(callback);
    }
    else if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Which means I can now do:

```
// get value from web storage
getStorageItem(webStorage, key, function(value) {

    if (value) {
        // whatever I want with the value
    }
});
```